# The jboss server is not connecting

Tags: linux, maven, unix, jboss, host

While I use the connect statement, it shows the following error

```
The controller is not available at localhost:9999: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012174:
Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection failed: JBAS012174: Could not
connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection failed: Connection refused
[disconnected /]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with connecting to the native management interface on port 9999 and all I ended up needing to do was enable the interface by adding the following to the standalone.XML file:

```
<management-interfaces>
  <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
      <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
  </native-interface>
         :
<management-interfaces>
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual native management binding (HOST:PORT) is defined in JBoss configuration file as interface name="management" and socket-binding name="management-native". By default they use localhost and 9999.

When install system service, it is necessary to specify the correct /controller host:port values if management binding has been updated.

The error below in the log indicates the CLI command line cannot connect to the management interface when shutting down:

Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection failed

Confirm the /controller parameter used when configuring system service matches the management interface and socket binding definition in JBoss configuration file (standalone.xml / domain.xml and host.xml).

When configuring system service, if not specified, the default configuration for controller is :

```
/controller HOST:PORT    The host and port of the management interface. If omitted, the default is localhost:9999.
```

Change this parameter to match the management interface and socket binding settings in the JBoss configuration file:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="192.168.0.1"/>
    </interface>
......
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
```

With such configuration above you need to specify /controller as below to install the system service

```
service.bat install /startup /controller=192.168.0.1:9999 /config standalone-customized-1.xml
```

If jboss.socket.binding.port-offset is set, confirm actual port number (after offset) is passed in /controller parameter. For example, if jboss.socket.binding.port-offset is set as 300 in standalon.xml, you need to use 10299 (default 9999 + 300) as PORT number to install system service:

```
service.bat install /startup /controller=192.168.0.1:10299 /config standalone-customized-2.xml
```